# ipad viewport moves

Tags: css, ipad, html, safari, viewport

Does anyone know if it is possible to disable the moving of the viewport on the ipad?

I have my viewport setup correctly like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

What I'd like to do is prevent/disable the ability to drag the website around as it shows safari's textured background when done so.

Comment: You can't, that is Safari's behavior

Answer (score 1):

I honestly didn't test this with the viewport you're using but with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;">
```

it seems to work for me. At least I'm unable to drag to the side on my iPad with iOS 5.1 (top-down is always possible as far as I'm aware)

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the page matches the viewport width correctly, then you cannot drag the page horizontally (see http://jquerymobile.com/test/ for an example - you never see the textured background on left or right of page).

Maybe if you get the height correct as well?

Some UI can be disabled with Javascript e.g. Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859207/436776 prevents page-scrolling from occurring, which might solve your problem. Or maybe stopping the event in `ongesturestart` helps?

One final issue to also look at is orientation change. It is super messy to deal with properly, especially the interference with zoom levels. You can disable zoom by using `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />` but that causes other problems to resolve, and causes other compromises.